# How to extract the id of textarea (which is dynamic in this case) in javascript after clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have the below given `JSP` code inside a `form` which is generating dynamic `div` element:

```
<div class="ans_panel<%=qcount%>">
    <textarea class="text_<%=qcount%>" id="add_answer<%=qcount%>" rows="0" cols="80"></textarea>

    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenAns" value="<%=qcount%>" />
    <br>
    <br>

    <button class="post<%=qcount%>" onclick="addAns();">Post Answer</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <button class="cancel<%=qcount%>">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass it to the javascript routine;

```
<button class="post<%=qcount%>" onclick="addAns('<%=qcount%>');">Post Answer</button>
...
function addAns(id) {
   var el = $("#text_" + id);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I used this but its not working. I have two values from database on jsp(qKey, question). On the basis of this key I have to submit an answer to that particular question. I am verifying this value in script but when I pass the value to script and take it back to jsp all the values in the jsp becomes null. As the form is dynamically generated, I am not able to get the qKey back.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
function addAns(el) {
    alert(el.id);
    document.getElementById("hiddenSubmitAns").value = "AddSubmit";
    var text = null;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        text = $("#add_answer" + i).val();
        if (text != "") {
            j = i;
            alert(text);
            break;
        }
    }
    text = text.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "");
    if (text == "") {
        alert("Please enter the answer");
        document.getElementById("#add_answer" + i).select();
        document.getElementById("#add_answer" + i).focus();
        return false;
    }
    document.abc.submit();
    return true;
}

<div class="ans_panel<%=qcount%>">
     <textarea class="text_<%=qcount%>" id="add_answer<%=qcount%>" rows="0" cols="80"></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" id="hiddenAns" value="<%=qcount%>" />
     <br>
     <br>
     <button class="post<%=qcount%>" onclick="addAns(this);">Post Answer</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <button class="cancel<%=qcount%>">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Note that I have added a parameter to `addAns` and then updated your `onclick` to pass `this`.

Then I am alerting `el.id`, or you could use `alert($(el).attr('id'));` if your using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Are there more than 1 text area on page?

If not then you can access it using `$("textarea")` and get its id using `$("textarea").attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery('[attribute^="value"]')`, it Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
var theTextArea = $('textarea[id^="add_answer"]');
```

then

```
var theId = theTextArea.attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].class.indexOf('text') === 0) {
         return elements[i].id;
    }
}
```